# GeoServer v2.14 Responses to DescribeFeatureType Requests

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, describe-feature-type

A browser's (Chrome) DescribeFeatureType request to GeoServer version 2.12 returns an inline XML response in the browser's window.

Using that same browser to send a DescribeFeatureType request to a GeoServer version 2.14, the response is a document that is downloaded to the Windows' Downloads directory with the filename `geoserver-describefeaturetype.application`. This document contains the same XML content as the inline XML response when requesting from GeoServer version 2.12.

Coincidently, QGIS is not able to resolve the DescribeFeatureType request to the GeoServer version 2.14 but does resolve the DescribeFeatureType request from GeoServer 2.12.

We don't see any settings in GeoServer to modify how it responds to DescribeFeatureType requests.

Interestingly, a browser's GetCapabilities request to both versions of GeoServer yields an inline XML response from GeoServer.

The DescribeFeatureType request is in the form `https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?request=DescribeFeatureType`

and the GetCapabilities request is in the form

`https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?request=GetCapabilities`

Most importantly, we want to get the WFS connection from QGIS to GeoServer version 2.14 working.  But we also want the inline response to a DescribeFeatureType request.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no problem in using GeoServer 2.16 with QGIS 3.11. Please clarify how it appears that your QGIS can't read DescribeFeatureType from your server.

Comment: You might be thinking about this the wrong way around. It's unlikely that GeoServer is giving different responses to the same request from different sources (unless you've tied it down with some security, but you've not mentioned that), it's much more likely that actual requests are different somehow.

Comment: The other possibility is the response is the same, and Qgis can't parse it.  This can happen with complex feature WFS

Answer (score 2):

A GetCapabilities request must include the service type, so `https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?request=GetCapabilities` is not correct, it should be:

> https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

This will give an XML result in your browser.

Similarly, a DescribeFeatureType request must include the service parameter and version, and ideally type to be described (otherwise you get all types), so should be something like:

> https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?request=DescribeFeatureType&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typename=your_type_name&

You can also add an output format depending on what's listed in the GetCapabilities response for your version of service.

For QGIS you just specify the service URL (without any WFS request parameters) so just:

> https://myserver.com/geoserver/mynamespace/wfs?

QGIS will (should) add appropriate WFS request parameters.

If QGIS (or any other client) can read the GetCapabilities response, but then fails in other operations you should check whether URLs in the GetCapabilities response are as expected.  There's no requirement for all advertised URLs to be the same, though it's common.

---

**Note**

`typename` vs. `typenames` in WFS requests

In a WFS 2.0.0 service the specification tells us to use `typename` for DescribeFeatureType request but `typenames` for GetFeature

Comment: Or you can use the global service from https://myserver.com/geoserver/wfs?

Comment: Thanks, @nmtoken.  I should have included the 'service=wfs` and `version=2.0.0` in my post to avoid confusion.  GeoServer fills in with default values if they are not present.  The results are identical regardless if I explicitly include them in the URL or not - I still receive a document in my Downloads directory than inline within the browser window.  Same with DescribeFeatureType.  I agree with how the QGIS URL should be supplied - I already did that.  I can see the layers, but when I double click on one of them to set a filter, I get the "DescribeFeatureType failed" message.

Comment: @user30184 - We have Global Services enabled in GeoServer.  I'm not an admin of the server and I don't quite understand what you mean by "use the global service from ...".  Can you clarify?

Comment: Global services are those which are not accessed by including the workspace part in the URL. localhost://geoserver/wfs is global while localhost://geoserver/topp/wfs, the URL model that was used in the answer, is pointing to a virtual service in the GeoServer vocubulary https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html. Versions 2.14 and 2.16 work for me with QGIS so the problem is not generally in the new version. Unfortunately I can't say why it fails for you.

Comment: @slalomchip I've answered keeping the OGC specification in mind and the answer is applicable to any WFS not just one supplied by GeoServer, I know that GeoServer is lax in following the standards, but really as we're talking about basic operations of a WFS, let's keep to the standard.  Note the standard tells us it must be `service=WFS&` and not per GeoServer documentation `service=wfs&`.    If the response in the browser to the WFS DescribeFeatureType is a download, then you have the wrong mime type, try `outputformat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/2.1.2&` assuming it's supported.

Comment: If QGIS fails in making a WFS DescribeFeatureType request, check the GetCapabilities response to make sure that the advertised URL for the DescribeFeatureType is correct.  You should also be able to use debugging tools (Fiddler for example) to see what actual request is sent by QGIS, and if you try that request in a browser you may find out the actual error.

Comment: @nmtoken and @user30184 We need to thoroughly review the GeoServer settings.  A `DescribeFeatureType` when specifying `version=1.1.0` gives the inline response like I want, but specifying WFS `version=1.1.0` in QGIS did not solve the `DescribeFeatureType failed` error.  The network is locked down and I don't have permissions to install Fiddler or similar. We'll have to thoroughly compare the GeoServer settings with other GeoServers we have.  I appreciate the comments you provided.

Comment: What URL is specified in the 1.1.0 GetCapabilities response for the describefeaturetype operation. Is it exactly the same the URL that works for you in the browser

Comment: Do you have access to the geoserver /Apache logs. To see what request is sent

Comment: @nmtoken - I don't have access to the logs but other team members do. Getting them to spend much time on it is a challenge because of all the other higher priority tasks. No one on the team claims to be an expert on GeoServer but they know enough to stand one up and basic configurations. Once a GeoServer gets set up, it is left fairly untouched. The URL I'm providing QGIS is the same that I'm providing the browser.

Comment: The question isn't about the URL you give to QGIS, vs the URL you write in a browser. It's about the URL in the GetCapabilities response document. It's not uncommon for these to be different.  That's what I was meaning.